# Get-MoveRequest not showing anything

Tags: exchange

Exchange 2016 on-prem.

Migration started in EAC still showing active half hour later. It's a large mailbox so I expect this.
[image]

Get-MoveRequest is not showing ANYTHING:
[image]

UPDATE:

This request failed because this mailbox was moved a few days ago and the request was deleted after completion in the GUI but apparently it wasn't really deleted because it still conflicts with this new move.

Comment: Hi, Try "Get-MoveRequest -BatchName alex3   | Get-MoveRequestStatistics", any results returned?

Comment: Nothing. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bTnqXd_aT3_PDyqF71bvjSHpQ7EQbc-X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @prl77 Hi, is there any update? Please check if the below info is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the answers in the following similar case are helpful to you: **[Get-MoveRequest not showing anything](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2317717-get-moverequest-not-showing-anything?page=1#entry-9170737)**

Based on my test, the move request would show in PowerShell when the request status was syncing or completed, the move request wouldn't do that when the request status was validating and failed.

Check if it's helpful to fix this issue if you run the cmdlet **`Get-MoveRequest | Remove-MoveRequest`** or refer to the following thread: **[Clear Move Request fails for "Microsoft Exchange Migration" system mailbox](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2160511-clear-move-request-fails-for-microsoft-exchange-migration-system-mailbox)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:
Get-MoveRequest –BatchName “MigrationService:Your Batch Name”